# Where can I get a version of Xcode that will run on 10.6.8 (the current version nolonger supports 10.6)?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, download, xcode

Where can I get a version of Xcode that will run on 10.6.8 (the current version nolonger supports 10.6)?

I tried inserting the original 10.6.8 Install disk in my laptop but it just pops back out again.  I did this incase there is a copy of Xcode on the disk.   But as the disk is rejected I guess that it only works when doing an OP Sys re-install?   Perhaps there was another disk that contained Xcode (if so it is now missing)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you can log into the iOS Developer Portal, do that and then search for Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard and you'll get Xcode 4 for 10.6.8. If you don't have access then you are out of luck.  If you have access https://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792 is the location.

Comment: xcode is on the CD.  Do you have another box you can try mounting the disk on?  (I've had issues with my laptop CDs).  You can create an iso on another box then copy the iso to your laptop, mount it and install xcode from there.

Answer (score 1):

`Developer.apple.com` should have everything you need.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=xcode

Answer (score 1):

On your shipped 2nd DVD, you can find an old version of Xcode 3.x; anyway, if you register yourself for free as a developer on their [site](http://developer.apple.com), you can get the latest 3.x version.

If you want a legal copy of the 4.x version, you have to pay a different type of account on the linked URL and then you can download the last compatible 4.2 version.

My personal advise is to try to virtualize either a more recent version of OS X (with the latest version of Xcode) in order to target more clients…